# Iterate XML in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am working on an XML content (below) and wanted to iterate the value of the Student element and corresponding value of Gender, and then finally check if the student name is Anne, print the Gender as Female.

However when I try using below script, the output I get is-

```
Anne is Male
Anne is Male
Anne is Female
```

What could be the issue here? Could I get some help here?

XML content:

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Objects>
      <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.CustomObject">
        <Property Name="Gender" Type="Application.String">Male</Property>
        <Property Name="Student" Type="Microsoft.Application.Service">John</Property>
      </Object>
      <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.CustomObject">
        <Property Name="Gender" Type="Application.String">Male</Property>
        <Property Name="Student" Type="Microsoft.Application.Service">Charles</Property>
      </Object>
    <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.CustomObject">
       <Property Name="Gender" Type="Application.String">Female</Property>
       <Property Name="Student" Type="Microsoft.Application.Service">Anne</Property>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

Here is the script:

```
[xml]$file = Get-Content C:\xml-report.xml
foreach ($obj in $file.Objects.Object.Property) {
  if('Student'-contains $obj.Name) {
    $name = $obj.'#text'
    }
  if('Gender' -contains $obj.Name) {
    $gend = $obj.'#text'  
    }
       if ($name = "Anne") { 
       Write-Host $name "is" $gend
    }
}
```

Comment: Your XML looks like it's the output of `Export-CliXml`.  Why not use `Import-CliXml`?

Comment: @BaconBits For me it looks like result of `ConvertTo-Xml`, which AFAIK use different format than `Export-CliXml` and does not have `ConvertFrom`/`Import` command.

Comment: Yes PetSerAl, the XML file was created using ConvertTo-Xml cmdlet. Is there a simpler way of converting to XML?

Answer (score 4):

You need to start iterating over the objects rather than the properties for this, then select the relevant data from each property of the object.

You also need to use the correct syntax for testing equality, in Powershell it is `-eq`. For more info type `Get-Help about_comparison_operators`

Try:

```
foreach ($obj in $file.Objects.Object) {
  $gend = $obj.Property | ? { $_.Name -eq 'Gender' } | Select -expand '#text'
  $name = $obj.Property | ? { $_.Name -eq 'Student' } | Select -expand '#text'
  if ($name -eq 'Anne') {
    Write-Output "$name is $gend"
  }
}
```

The `?` is an alias for `Where-Object` which allows you to filter a collection based on its properties.